# SQL Queries for combining data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would appreciate any help regarding the following challenge (for me). Really sorry for my novice question.

I have the following table ([USER ID] has borrowed the book entitled [Book Title] on [Timestamp]):

```
USER ID | Book Title | Timestamp
--------------------------------
   1    |   Alpha    | 10/10/2007
   2    |   Beta     | 12/02/2010
   3    |   Gama     | 03/05/2011
```

etc. What I would like is to make a list with the following type of rows:

```
UserID A | UserUD B | Book Title| Timestamp
```

If two [USER ID] have borrowed the same [Book Title], I would like to list them as above mentioned, but also keep the [Timestamp] of the latest borrowing.

Does anyone know how to write it in PHP?

Until now I have write the code for combining the users who have borrowed the same [Book Title] but I have not yet figured out how to attach the timestamp to this list.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: What if three people have borrowed the same book?

Comment: Then I would like to have the following:
(User A | User B | Book Title | Timestamp 1) - 
(User A | User C | Book Title | Timestamp 2) - 
(User B | User C | Book Title | Timestamp 3) - 
All the possible combinations are needed

Comment: If you really want to have it so you have a column for each user who has a book out, you will want to use a `PIVOT TABLE`.  Perhaps if you explain *why* you are wanting to do it this way, we can help guide you in a more appropriate direction.

Comment: Note that dates and times in SQL adhere to a specific format

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! In this case, the date is represented as a text (there is no need to be represented in a formal php date format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can then do this with a `join`:

```
select ft.userid as userid1, ft2.userid as userid2,  ft.booktitle,
       ft2.timestamp
from followingtable ft join
     followintable ft2
     on ft.booktitle = ft2.booktitle and
        ft.timestamp < ft2.timestamp;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I updated the question with what i have wrote until now